# python django, How to prohibit go to the next code from for loop

Tags: python, django

```
def redirectTest(item):
    try:
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
        }
        r = None
        try:
            r = requests.head(item, allow_redirects=False, headers=headers)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if r is not None:
            if r.status_code == 301:
                print("Tested: " + str(r.status_code))
            elif r.status_code == 302:
                print("Tested: " + str(r.status_code))
            else:
                print("Tested: " + str(r.status_code))
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print('error: ' + e)
    return

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def re_check_url(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            resolved_urls = ['twitch.tv/yumyumyu77']
            scheme_list = ['http://www.', 'http://', 'https://www.', 'https://']

            for item in resolved_urls:
                for scheme_item in scheme_list:
                    redirectTest(scheme_item + item)
            return JsonResponse({'res': 1})
        return JsonResponse({'res': 2})
```

This code checks `scheme + some url`'s responses.

But when I execute the code, my Django terminal prints:

```
 r_status_code: 301
 r_status_code: 301
 r_status_code: 200
[22/Oct/2018 23:54:49] "POST /re/check/url/ HTTP/1.1" 200 10
 r_status_code: 301
```

**Problem:**

I think it means that `return JsonResponse({'res': 1})` this line is ahead, and `print("Tested: " + str(r.status_code))` this line is after or later.

Sometimes it prints ordinarily, but sometimes it prints abnormally.

**Question:**

I learned that Python code is executed line by lines from top to bottom, but It seems like it is not doing so.

Why does this happened? and how can I fix it?

It's executing order is not what I expected.

**Edit:**

I tried to use `Lock()`

```
    for item in resolved_urls:
        for scheme_item in scheme_list:
            from threading import Lock
            _lock = Lock()
            with _lock:
                redirectTest(scheme_item + item)
```

But It does not seems to be working well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is python's print synchronized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393310/is-pythons-print-synchronized)

Comment: Seems from skimming your question that 2 different subsystems are logging the same event and sometimes the order flip-flops depending on what system "beats" the other to the log message. Why does this matter? What needs to be "fixed" here? If the order of these log messages matters for any reason I'd say that's a sign of a serious flaw in the design.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Yes, I need clear order, Because I have to send response to users depending on server computer's requests and responses(It's executing order, result or else)

Comment: Sorry but you're not doing anything (apparent to me) asynchronously, so I'm still failing to understand why the order of these log lines matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is actually working correctly. 200 is success, and it redirects to the success page. Then it runs your last loop.

Comment: Thankyou but in my computer, when I try it almost 10 times at once, that happens.