# Printing To Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that will be printing quite a few lines to terminal. When I start the script for the first 10 or so lines it's perfectly fine but then the prints start going wrong. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid? I/O Buffer?

[image: This is how the print statements look in the terminal]

```
def printing_test():    
   print(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + '[' + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + '] ' + '[System] - ' + Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '[Task ' + '1' + f" | SYSTEM] - Print Line 1..\r" + Style.RESET_ALL)
   sleep(0.3)    
   print(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + '[' + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + '] ' + '[System] - ' + Fore.MAGENTA + Style.BRIGHT + '[Task ' + '1' + f" | SYSTEM] - Print Line 2\r" + Style.RESET_ALL)    
   sleep(0.3)    
   print(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + '[' + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + '] ' + '[System] - ' + Fore.YELLOW + Style.BRIGHT + '[Task ' + '1' + f" | SYSTEM] - Print Line 3..\r" + Style.RESET_ALL)    
   sleep(0.3)    
   print(Fore.WHITE + Style.BRIGHT + '[' + datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + '] ' + '[System] - ' + Fore.GREEN + Style.BRIGHT + '[Task ' + '1' + f" | SYSTEM] - Print Line 4\r" + Style.RESET_ALL)    
   sleep(60)
```

I realise this also probably isn't the most elegant way of presenting these prints, however, for now I'm just after the answer as to why the print statements start to screw up at around line 10.

Thank you!

Comment: How are you calling that method? In a basic loop?, or using some sort of parallel execution? Please show that code, too, as it is most relevant.

Comment: This one is through threads.

Comment: Your threads seem to have gotten all tangled up.

Comment: Probably related (but does not really provide a solution): https://stackoverflow.com/q/4393310/1639625

Comment: I think that's what i'm looking for. Thanks bro.

Comment: What happens when you run the program with `python -u program.py`? (The `-u` flag makes output unbuffered.)